# Get a Visual Studio project (MSBuild) to know the Team Build output location

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have this custom build step form my project:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <WriteLinesToFile Condition="" File="$(OutputPath)\env.config"
                    Lines="$(Configuration)" Overwrite="true">
  </WriteLinesToFile>
</Target>
```

Basically it outputs the build configuration to a file.

This works fine when building in Visual Studio.  Team Build decided to make things harder.  The OutputPathfor Team Build is in a different spot (not bin\$(Configuration))

I know how to find out if the build is part of a team build (`Condition=" '$(TeamBuildConstants)' == '_TEAM_BUILD_' "`) but unless I want to hard code the path, I can't see a way to get the Team Build path.

Any ideas on how to find out (in the project, the the Team Build file) what the output location is?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use $(OutDir) when running in Team Build:

http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/07/preserving-output-directory-structures-in-orcas-team-build.aspx

So you could use the _TEAM_BUILD_ condition and have two calls - one with OutputPath and one with OutDir.